# C# - Read between parentheses in RichTextBox

Tags: c#

So I want to find out what is in between specific parentheses in a `richtextbox`. For example:

```
if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("testname(") {
    // Find what is in brackets of testname()

    String outcome = //what is in brackets of testname()
}
```

This may be hard to understand, but let's say this is the `richtextbox`:

```
testname(name)
```

Then the string outcome would be `name`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expression to get the value between the parenthesis.

```
string text = richTextBox1.Text; // testname("some text")
string value = Regex.Match(text, @"\(([^)]*)\)").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string outcome = richTextBox1.Text;
outcome = outcome.Substring(outcome.IndexOf("(")+1, outcome.IndexOf(")") - outcome.IndexOf("("));
```

Answer (score 0):

wrote from iPad so not tested, but something along these lines should get you there

```
String a = "testname(";

String b = "testname(Val)";
int x = b.IndexOf(a);

If (richTextBox1.Text.Contains(a)){
if (x != -1) 
{
    string final = b.Substring(x + a.Length);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex would be the way to go.

Here I am matching exactly a parenthesis followed by any character one or more times followed by another parenthesis.

You have to escape parenthesis.

```
string yourText = richTextBox1.Text;
//string cow = "this is some text(this is the text you want)"; 
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\(.+\)");
Match match = regex.Match(yourText);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value); // with cow -> this is the text you want
} // can have else
```

You may want to consider using `*` instead of `+` in case they don't have any input between the `( )` Example: `Regex regex = new Regex(@"\(.*\)");`
Now it matches any character 0 or more times

Answer (score -1):

```
string textBox = richTextBox1.Text;
```

textBox = textBox.Replace("testname(", "");

// Now textBox has the string you are looking for